# Disable "Email organizer" by default in Microsoft Outlook email meeting invites on macOS

Tags: macos, email, ms-office, calendar, microsoft

I'm using the Microsoft Outlook Office 365 desktop client for macOS, via my work computer. Version 16.58 currently.

When I receive a meeting invite, the option is checked on by default to "Email organizer" when responding to an event.

Maybe I don't fully grok the Outlook way of doing things, but I don't want to email the sender every time I accept an invite. It pollutes their inbox and my "Sent" folder.

But this checkbox is re-enabled for every new meeting invite I receive.

How can I set the default behavior to *NOT* "Email organizer" when I respond to an event?

---

Screenshot:

[image: Email organizer in Microsoft Outlook 365 for macOS]

> RSVP to this event
> Optional message to organizer
> **Email organizer**  (slider/checkbox)
> Accept | Tentative | Decline | Propose New Time

In previous versions of Outlook, this same behavior (?) may have been phrased:

> Respond With Comments
> Respond Without Comments
> Do Not Send a Response